# How to get started/use matplotlib in kivy

Tags: python, matplotlib, kivy

I have recently learned a bit of matplotlib and would like to use it within kivy. I have read a little documentation on the garden here and there but don't really understand it.
I have installed kivy garden and matplotlib but don't know how to proceed from here. I simply want to add a already completed matplotlib graph into kivy.
I would appreciate a step by step simplified set of instructions of how to get what I already coded into kivy and get it to display.
Thanks

Comment: I did read it. What is the problem? Title is relevant, I outlined the problem and added tags.

Comment: Stackoverflow is more targeted to specific questions like "why does this line produce an error" or "how can I turn the background of a kivy widget blue". You can save a png from matplotlib and display it with an image from kivy.

Comment: Oh I see, this was my second post here so I didn't know. Guess I'll have to look into animating the graph instead then.

Comment: Are there convenient solutions for interactive figures in Kivy after 4 years? Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68345620/deploy-flexible-user-interfaces-for-simple-data-analysis-scripts-in-python

Answer (score 38):

Here is the simplest example possible for kivy-garden matplotlib and kivy. If you would like to do more advanced things, check out their examples: https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.matplotlib/tree/master/examples
I think it should be enough to get you started with your plot.

Below I am adding it to a BoxLayout, you can add more widgets to this BoxLayout or add this BoxLayout somewhere else.

python code example.py:

```
from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1, 23, 2, 4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        box = BoxLayout()
        box.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf()))
        return box

MyApp().run()
```

[image]

Comment: But the problem is that it is not an interactive figure!!! it's just a picture with no activity to zoom or cursor!

Comment: matplotlib is not the right library for interactive figures IMHO. I would suggest to look into bokeh or plotly for a start. (not sure why so many !)

Comment: I wished to use an interactive figure in raspberry pi and touch screen do you still believe bokeh and plotly are better in touch screen and raspberry pi?