# Matplotlib imshow and kivy

Tags: python, matplotlib, kivy

I have a 3D numpy array, representing a 3D tomographic image I = [i,j,k].

I started to learn kivy as I need to do a simple GUI consisting of a 2D image viewer for each slice of the 3D (s = [i,:,:]) image and a slicer to move across planes.

I usually perform all visualization via matplotlib and I tough that the easiest way will be to connect matplotlib to the kivy. How can I do it?
I saw another question which ask a similar question, but only with the plot function, and the methodology does not seems to work for imshow. ([How to get started/use matplotlib in kivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44905416/how-to-get-started-use-matplotlib-in-kivy?answertab=active#tab-top)).

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the example for details.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg


img = mpimg.imread('ac013.JPG')
lum_img = img[:, :, 0]
plt.imshow(lum_img, cmap="nipy_spectral")
plt.colorbar()


class TestApp(App):
    title = "Kivy Garden Matplolib & imshow()"

    def build(self):
        box = BoxLayout()
        box.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf()))
        return box


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Img01]

Comment: Your solution works as expected, thanks. In your opinion, if I want to do an "slicer" of a 3d image with options such as "change the window level" or do a manual ROI, is this a valid way to work? Or I should use another way of visualitzation?