# How can I get matplotlib working in Kivy?

Tags: python, matplotlib, kivy

I want to display a matplotlib plot inside my Python Kivy application.
I followed the answer from here: [Matplotlib imshow and kivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51860032/matplotlib-imshow-and-kivy)
However when I try to run this I always get the following import error:
[image: import error]
Kivy, its depencensies and matplotlib are installed and upgraded to its newest versions (kivy=1.11.1, Kivy-Garden=0.1.4, matplotlib=3.1.3). Kivy and matplotlib both work if they are run independend.

It seems like kivy.garden does not contain matplotlib anymore.
If I run the example found here: https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.matplotlib/blob/master/examples/test_backend.py
I face the same issue.
Did anyone solve this problem or knows a version combination that works?

The full source code can be found here: https://github.com/Pyhti1/MNIST_Tester