# Deploy flexible user interfaces for simple data analysis scripts in python

Tags: python, user-interface, config

This question needs hints from the python community on how to create simple, flexible user interfaces for python scripts. The idea is simple: a script creats plots based on parameters from a config file. Instead of editing the config file and re-running the script over and over again, the user should be able to:

1. display the content of the config file in a nice App interface,
2. play with the editable parameter fields, and
3. run the script, which ideally live-updates the plots and saves the output files.

I know that there are many tools out there, and I tried some of them, but I figured four main limitations so far:

- Window-based Qt-like librarys like PySimpleGUI are not flexible: window widths and element positions are hard-coded and don't work work for an arbitrary number of elements that should be auto-generated from the config file. (In addition, these GUIs are often not "modern" and display-responsive.)
- Web-based tools (which I would prefer most) often run on *localhost* and therefore do not allow for file-system i/o and other more complex system operations beyond the web folder.
- Developer-savy tools like Jupyter Notebooks are too complex for a simple users,
- My patience to try out each and every single python-App generator (-;

What could be a good solution to these requirements?
Can you provide an example App with your favourite tool for the following minimal example:

config.cfg:

```
[files]
file_input  = data.csv
file_output = output.pdf
[params]
param1 = 42
```

data.csv:

```
id,value
0,42
1,23
2,314
3,37
```

Script.py (read config, read data, do calculations, save plots):

```
import configparser
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
_ = config.read('config.cfg')
    
data = pandas.read_csv(config['files']['file_input'])
data['result'] = data['value'] * float(config['params']['param1'])
print('Calculated: %.1f' % data.result.mean())

with matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages(config['files']['file_output']) as fig:
    plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
    plt.plot(data.id, data.result)
    fig.savefig()
    plt.close()
    
print('Done.')
```

Exemplary illustration how a potential GUI could look like:
[image]